# How can I open Pandoc in a particular directory in order to run a command line?

Tags: command-line, pandoc

I just install [Pandoc](https://pandoc.org/) on Windows10. I have several **.docx** files from a folder ( **D:\DE SCANAT\Docx** ) and I want to convert all them (batch) into **.txt**

I must use this line command for this:

```
for i in *.docx ; do echo "$i" && pandoc -s --wrap=none $i -o $i.txt ; done
```

My problem: where to put that line, because I cannot open Pandoc in that folder, like I use to do with CMD. ?

Can anyone tell me how can I use that line, so as to change my files from the folder?

Also, I get this error if I use Powershell command line:

```
At line:1 char:4
+ for i in *.docx ; do echo "$i" && pandoc -s --wrap=none $i -o $i.txt  ...
+    ~
Missing opening '(' after keyword 'for'.
At line:1 char:21
+ for i in *.docx ; do echo "$i" && pandoc -s --wrap=none $i -o $i.txt  ...
+                     ~
Missing statement body in do loop.
At line:1 char:32
+ for i in *.docx ; do echo "$i" && pandoc -s --wrap=none $i -o $i.txt  ...
+                                ~~
The token '&&' is not a valid statement separator in this version.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingOpenParenthesisAfterKeyword
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, The command you provided seems to be a shell script using a Unix-style loop. So, this command works only on Unix, but not in windows10:

```
for i in *.docx ; do echo "$i" && pandoc -s --wrap=none $i -o $i.txt ; done
```

**If you want to convert on Windows10, follow the next simple steps:**

**1. Open Powershell**

Got to the folder you have the files, using this command:

```
cd 'D:\DE SCANAT\Docx\'
```

**2. After that, just copy and paste this command. And wait little while for the conversion to take place. It depends of the size of .docx files.**

```
$docxFiles = Get-ChildItem -Filter "*.docx"

foreach ($file in $docxFiles) {
    $txtFile = [System.IO.Path]::ChangeExtension($file.FullName, ".txt")
    & pandoc -s $file.FullName -t plain -o $txtFile
}
```

Comment: You're missing `--wrap=none` part in your PS code. Also, could just use `-Path` in `Get-ChildItem` instead of splitting it into 2 parts, to simplify it a bit.

Comment: I didn't forget anything. I left room for additions for those who know better. Please put your solution to the problem in a new answer.